# What does this "Icon" mean in Intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why is there that symbol next to all my classes. This happened after I renamed my packages from inside file explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means :

> Java class located out of the source root.

See [Configuring Content Roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html).

All the IntelliJ icons:
[IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0 Help: Symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html).